# React no enabled plugin supports this MIME type for PDF in Iframe on Tablet & Mobile device toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pdf

Trying to display a PDF in an iframe, it works perfectly on desktop view, but when I try to load it from Tablet or Mobile it does not display. The body element of the iframe then says "no enabled plugin supports this MIME type". I can, however, load the PDF on desktop view then change to tablet or mobile and it will display. Any ideas on how to get it to load on the tablet and mobile views?

Here's the iframe:

```
<iframe id="documentObject" name="documentIframe" src={fileSrc} title={fileName} height="100%" width="100%" />
```